# Draw Comparison between List Obtained from XML File and List Obtained from SubFolders and Modifying XML File Accordingly

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, linq-to-xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MainClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Items>
    <Settings xsi:type="FileModel">
      <Name>FileOne</Name>
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
      <IsHidden>false</IsHidden>
    </Settings>
    <Settings xsi:type="FileModel">
      <Name>FileTwo</Name>
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
      <IsHidden>false</IsHidden>
    </Settings> 
   <Settings xsi:type="ServerModel">
      <Name>DelRep</Name>
      <IsActive>false</IsActive>
      <IsHidden>false</IsHidden>
    </Settings>
  </Items>
  <DirectoryPath>D:\MainFolder</DirectoryPath>
</MainClass>
```

I have the above XML File . I am trying to draw a comparison between the names of the set of sub-folders present within "D:\MainFolder" and the  Element in the above XML. If a Certain Folder is Not Present in the Location D:\MainFolder I want to Remove the entire Settings Element of that Given Name.

For Example if there is No Sub folder Named FileOne ,  I want this Entire Junk of XML Code

```
<Settings xsi:type="FileModel">
  <Name>FileOne</Name>
  <IsActive>true</IsActive>
  <IsHidden>false</IsHidden>
</Settings>
```

To be Removed

**Right Now I have the Names in the XML Stored as**

```
List<string> namesInXML = settingsFile.Descendants("Items").Elements("Settings ").Where(x => x.Attribute(nameSpace + "type").Value == "FileModel").Select(x => x.Element("Name").Value).ToList();
```

**and the Subfolders in the D:\MainFolder**

**Obtained from : -**

```
IEnumerable<string> fileNames = new DirectoryInfo(Path).EnumerateFiles("fileServer.config", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(fi => fi.DirectoryName).Select(dirPath => dirPath.Substring(Path.Length));
```

**Saved in this List**

```
List<string> subFolderNames = fileNames.ToList();
```

How can I use these two List two fulfill my Requirement ?

Comment: Linq is query that is designed for reading (not writing or deleting).  The is better to use a for loop : foreach(string nameInXml in settingsFile.Descendants("Items").Elements("Settings ").Where(x => x.Attribute(nameSpace + "type").Value == "FileModel")) { nameInXml.Remove();}.  Doing it with a for loop you don't have create a list.

Answer (score 0):

By these two lists implement your requirements:

```
           namesInXML.ForEach(name =>
            {
                if (!subFolderNames.Contains(name))
                {
                    settingsFile.Descendants("Items").Elements("Settings").
                    Where(x => x.Attribute(nameSpace + "type").Value == "FileModel" && x.Element("Name").Value.Equals(name)).
                    First().Remove();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get removing folder names with using `Except();`

```
var removingNames = namesInXML.Except(subFolderNames).ToList();
```

Then remove these names from XML;

```
foreach (var item in removingNames)
{
    settingsFile.Descendants("Items").Elements("Settings").
    Where(x => x.Attribute(nameSpace + "type").Value == "FileModel" && x.Element("Name").Value.Equals(item)).
    First().Remove();
}
```